# How to rotate UIView in 3D?

Tags: ios, uiview, transform, catransform3d, catransform3drotate

I have very simple task, but I can't understand CATransform3DRotate.
I have 3 UIImageView with equal height and width, and I need set some transformation for left and right items for next result:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15196617/result.png

Original screen:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15196617/original.png

My sources:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = -1.f / self.prevItemImageView.bounds.size.width;
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, (CGFloat) -(M_PI / 3.f), 0, 1.f, 0);
self.prevItemImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.f, 0.5f);
self.prevItemImageView.layer.transform = transform;

transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = -1.f / self.nextItemImageView.bounds.size.width;
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, (CGFloat) (M_PI / 3.f), 0, 0.5f, 0);
self.nextItemImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.f, 0.5f);
self.nextItemImageView.layer.transform = transform;
```

It is not work.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is apply the transform with altered `.m34` component to the superlayer of your image views, as a `sublayerTransform`. That is what gives transforms on the image views the appearance of depth.

This image started life as a square. But it looks rotated in 3D because its superlayer has a `sublayerTransform`:

[image]